# I need the algorithm for knapsack unbounded problem with atmost k number of repetitions for an item or weight

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, greedy

for example,
if i have weights=[20,10,30,40]
and values=[5,10,30,20]
and maximum weight that the bag
can store = 100
k=2, that is any weight can be
repeated atmost 2times.
The problem here is the values are profit percentages.
so the optimal answer for this
is (30 * 2) + (40 * 1), whose profit
is 2*(30 * 30/100) + 1 * (40*20/100) = 26.

```
Thanks in advance...
```

Comment: Why is the answer 2 * 30 + 20 = 80?  Wouldn't 30kg x 2 + 10kg x 2 + 20kg x 1 = 100kg be better at 2 * 30 + 2 x 10 + 1 x 5 = 85?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very easy.

1. Divide value by weight and call this R.
2. Sort the list according to R and value.  i.e. where R is different, R is used.  Where R is equal, value is used.

For your example, this results in:

```
w=[20,10,30,40], v=[5,10,30,20], r=[0.25, 1, 1, 0.5]
```

Then we sort it:

```
w=[30,10,40,20], v=[30,10,20,5], r=[1, 1, 0.5, 0.25]
```

Then we traverse w, and take up to 2 per index like below.

```
idx = 0, weight = 100, val = 0, ki = 0;
weight >= w[idx], weight -= w[idx], val += v[idx], ki++; // 0, 70, 30, 1
weight >= w[idx], weight -= w[idx], val += v[idx], ki++; // 0, 40, 60, 2
ki > k so increment index and reset ki. // 1, 40, 60, 0
weight >= w[idx], weight -= w[idx], val += v[idx], ki++; // 1, 30, 70, 1
weight >= w[idx], weight -= w[idx], val += v[idx], ki++; // 1, 20, 80, 2
ki > k so increment index and reset ki. // 2, 20, 80, 0
weight < w[idx], so increment idx // 3, 20, 80, 0
weight >= w[idx], weight -= w[idx], val += v[idx], ki++; // 3, 00, 85, 1
weight == 0, so terminate.
```

That would result in code that looks like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < weight.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        if (weight >= w[i])
        {
            weight -= w[i];
            val += v[i];
        }
        else
        {
             break;
        }
    }
}
```